# register an external exporter to pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, dataformat

I would like to add a format to export plots in a pyqtgraph application. I've dived in the code looking for a way to do that, but from outside the library source code didn't work. Or at least I couldn't make it work.

Looking how the exporters in the library work, I thought that replicating, for example what the [CSVExporter](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/exporters/CSVExporter.py) does, would work. In short, a sample code like:

```py
from pyqtgraph.exporters.Exporter import Exporter

class DataFormatExporter(Exporter):
    Name = "DataFormat from plot data"
    # (...) pure copy of the rest

DataFormatExporter.register()
```

The only exported that doesn't do this last call to register is the [PrintExporter](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/exporters/PrintExporter.py) but all the others. This method 'register' is a @classmethod in the [Exporter](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/exporters/Exporter.py) superclass.

But if I test the code, the exception says that the newer class doesn't have the register defined:

```
AttributeError: type object 'DataFormatExporter' has no attribute 'regiter'
```

The closest reference to what I'm looking is a [post in a pyqtgraph google group](https://groups.google.com/g/pyqtgraph/c/X-NlCaS5x3s/m/GZHnyUQTDAAJ) and its steps 1 and 2 are just what I've thought should be and what I've tried.

Any hint?

Comment: According to the error message you have a typo: change `regiter` to `register`

Comment: Oh! My mind was reading what I thought I wrote and not what in fact I wrote. Lont time moving things around and experimenting if there could be different, and all was a typo! THANKS!